# Python imports without "from"

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have a project with the following directory structure:

dir1
--dir2
----file1.py
----file2.py
--file3.py

In file3, I call a function in file1. In file1, it calls a function in file2, so it imports file2. Other files in dir2 are also imported by file1.

Currently, file1 causes a ModuleNotFound error on the line
`import file2`. This can be resolved by changing it to `from dir2 import file2`, but the issue is I would need to go through all the files in dir2 and try to fix the imports.

dir2 is a project found on Github and I would really not want to change all the imports every time I pull any changes. Is there a way to import file2 for use in file1, without having to change the imports?

I am using Python 3.9.12.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by having to change all the imports?

Comment: Change all the imports of format`import file` into `from dir2 import file`. Do you want the names of the directory and the files?

Comment: If it's a project you found on GitHub, can you just `pip install` it? (or use another package manager). Copying multiple source files from random places is likely to lead to trouble - either with execution or attribution.  You might also be able to use `sed` to recursively rewrite the import blocks: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/ but @joshua-taylor-epinette's plan below is much preferred.

Comment: @SarahMesser you should just definitely install it. Either install it as a separate project or package it up yourself

Comment: What is the github repo that corresponds to `dir2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python performs module resolution based on the `sys.path` variable. You can append `dir2` to this path so that any imports within it can be resolved:

*file3.py*

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("dir")

<other imports>
```

Alternatively, you can augment `sys.path` by using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```bash
$ PYTHONPATH=dir python3 file3.py
```

---

Keep in mind that path modifications are typically a code smell and should only be used when absolutely necessary. You can most likely resolve the root problem by having this "directory" (third party dependency) included in your project as a true pip installed dependency, then it will be "on path". Beyond that, you should only override third party code through your first party modules, not by adding files directly into their directories.

i.e.

```
from <dependency> import <class>

class App<Class>(<Class>):
    def overriden_method(self):
        return "my custom functionality"
```

---

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: As you said, path modifications are typically a code smell. Is this the only way to do what I'm thinking of?

Comment: @PeriodicParticle no. The way this is *supposed* to work is you should be *installing the project on github*. Then simply import it normally, like you would any library.

Comment: @PeriodicParticle in any case, using this approach is really probably not what you should be doing

Comment: Well, you probably should have this "directory" which is really a GitHub repo be included in your project as a dependency and installed by `pip`, then it will be on path. But beyond that, you shouldn't be including your own file in this "dependency", you should reference it from one of your first party modules. Through one of those two options, you can clean this up.

Comment: That was probably the answer I was looking for. If you want you can put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer with that additional information.

Comment: @PeriodicParticle There are definitely situations where this has to be done, albeit rare. I think it is valid to directly answer the question being asked but make a recommendation to an alternative (with warning).